# How to reverse array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array:

```
Array ( [2294] => 1 [2292] => 1 [2296] => 1 )
```

How can I reverse it to

```
Array ( [2296] => 1 [2292] => 1 [2294] => 1 )
```

TRIED **array_reverse()** but didn't work. What I am missing?

```
$array = array_reverse($array); // did not work
```

**EDIT: I do not want numeric (order sort) I just need to reverse bottom keys to top, and vice versa**

Comment: How exactly did u try the array_reverse function?

Comment: read about `preserve_keys` in `array_reverse`

Comment: I hope you didn't try to create an array with that code.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the [`preserve_keys`](http://php.net/array_reverse) parameter to `TRUE`:

```
$result = array_reverse($array, TRUE);
print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [2296] => 1
    [2292] => 1
    [2294] => 1
)
```

[**Demo.**](https://eval.in/81682)

Answer (score 2):

Yes You can do it by [krsort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.krsort.php) in php. As you need to sort based on key

```
    $array = array( 2294 => 1, 2292 => 1, 2296 => 1 );
    krsort($array);

    print_r($array)
```

Output:-

```
Array
(
    [2296] => 1
    [2294] => 1
    [2292] => 1
)
```

**Edit:-** You can also achieve by set the [preserve_keys](http://php.net/array_reverse#preserve_keys) parameter to `TRUE` in [array_reverse()](http://php.net/array_reverse)

```
   $array = array_reverse($array, TRUE);
   print_r($array);
```

<kbd>[Working Demo](http://ideone.com/2zKTti)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You have to sort on the key: look at [this table](http://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php)

You need the `ksort()` or `krsort()` functions

Comment: I do not want numeric (order sort) I just need to reverse bottom keys to top, and vice versa

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$array = array( 2294 => 1, 2292 => 1, 2296 => 1 );
$reversed = array_reverse( $array, true );
```